# Making 1,3,5-Tribromobenzene from Phenol

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

The problem was to make 1,3,5-Tribromobenzene from Phenol.

I thought to do it the following way:

- React phenol with $\ce{Br2/H2O}$.
- Then add $\ce{Zn}$ dust to get the product.

Now I am in doubt whether the second step would even work.

Are there any better method of doing this ?

Comment: I may be missing something obvious, but it's going to be tough to get rid of that hydroxyl. Zn won't do it.

Comment: @jerepierre that's what I was also thinking.

Comment: Why do you think Zn won't do it?The same reaction works for phenol. What makes it different here?

Comment: @KaranSingh I haven't looked into it, but I expect bromine will be reduced off before a hydroxyl group.

Answer (score 1):

1. First react phenol with ammonia in presence of zinc chloride to obtain aniline.

[image]

2. Then react aniline with bromine water to form 1,3,5-tribromoaniline 
   [image]
3. Then react 1,3,5-tribromoaniline  with sodium nitrite and hydrochloric acid at 273 K to form 1,3,5 tribromobenzenediazonium chloride.

[image]

4. Then react the diazonium salt with ethanol/phosphorous acid and water in presence of copper to form  1,3,5 tribromonbenzene.

[image]

Detail explanation about the reaction, conditions  and the mechanism is [given here](http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV2P0592) by actually conducting the experiment.